# VScode C debug problem with unable to find corresponding c file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I use vscode debug, and upon meeting function like printf(), it will generate an error message saying the certain file cannot be found

> Unable to open 'acrt_iob_func.c': Unable to read file
> 'c:_\M\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt\stdio\acrt_iob_func.c'
> (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file
> 'c:_\M\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt\stdio\acrt_iob_func.c').

The C file at the end (acrt_iob_func.c) varies.
Using gcc as my compiler help are appreciated.

Comment: Did you check that this file exists? -- The path looks strange with this underscore as first character after the drive specification. Is your configuration correct? (VS Code seems to be overly complicated compared to other IDEs.)

Comment: @thebusybee The file does not exist in the path which the error message gave, neither is it anywhere on my laptop. The underscore is a folder that somehow exists right under C:\, (literally there's a folder with name '_'). since I don't have the files under stdio folder, is it possible to download all those missing files, and where should I configure it to make it look for needed files under a certain directory?

Comment: OK. From the path I already suspected this, and your comment seems to confirm this, the missing source is part of the library. Apparently you tried to step into `printf()`. Commonly we don't have these sources, as they are not necessary for our debugging purposes.

Comment: You can proceed by stepping **over** calls to such standard functions, or ignore the message and "continue until the function is left," or try to find the sources at the MinGW project (make sure you look for the correct version), or anything else. I choose the first option regularly. Errors are by 99,99% in my code.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks a lot for your answer! Indeed stepping over is better since I don't really need to look into printf function. Also I have added skip command in launch.json.

Answer (score 0):

Skip command to add into launch.json under "setupCommands" for muting warning:

```
{
    "description": "Skip stdio-common files",
    "text": "-interpreter-exec console \"skip -gfi stdio/*.c\""
},
```